# Converting $p \leftrightarrow q$ to disjunctive normal form

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, disjunctive-normal-form

I started like this:
\begin{align*}
p &\leftrightarrow q\\
(p \to q) &\wedge (q \to p)\\
(q \vee \neg p) &\wedge (p \vee \neg q)
\end{align*}
But I'm not sure how to continue and how to change this formula to disjunctive normal form.

Comment: [conjunctive normal form (CNF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) is a conjunction of [clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)), where a clause is a disjunction of [literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(mathematical_logic)).

Comment: [disjunctive normal form (DNF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) : "Converting a formula to DNF involves using logical equivalences, such as the double negative elimination, De Morgan's laws, and the distributive law."

Comment: By [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic) : $(q ∨ ¬p) ∧ (p ∨ ¬q) \equiv [(q ∨ ¬p) ∧ p] ∨ [(q ∨ ¬p) ∧ ¬q]$. Then apply distributivity again, and exploit the fact that $(FALSE \lor \phi) \equiv \phi$.

Comment: Given the work you've shown in your post, you've successfully arrived at conjunctive normal form of $p\iff q$. So I edited the body of your post assuming that, as expressed in the title, you also want to express the proposition in disjunctive normal form. Please confirm?

Comment: That's true @amWhy, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get to DNF:
\begin{align*}
&p \leftrightarrow q\\
\equiv &(p \to q) \wedge (q \to p)
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\,\,\,\,\text{(Definition of iff)}\\
\equiv &(\neg p \vee q) \wedge (\neg q \vee p)
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\,\,\text{(Eliminate $\to$)}\\
\equiv &((\neg p \wedge \neg q)\vee (\neg p\wedge p)) \vee ((q \wedge \neg q)\vee (q \wedge  p))
\qquad\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{(Distribution)}\\
\equiv &((\neg p \wedge \neg q)\vee \textrm{F}) \vee (\textrm{F}\vee (q \wedge  p))
\qquad\text{(Since $(\neg p \wedge p)=(q \wedge \neg q)=\textrm{F}$))}\\
\equiv &(\neg p \wedge \neg q)
\vee (q \wedge  p)
\qquad\qquad \text{(Since $(\neg p \wedge \neg q)\vee \textrm{F}=(\neg p \wedge \neg q)$, and $\textrm{F}\vee (q \wedge  p)=(q \wedge  p))$}
\end{align*}